# CUDA syntax highlighting in Qt Creator

Tags: cuda, syntax-highlighting, qt-creator

Is someone aware of a method to highlight CUDA code while using Qt Creator? I could do so in vim and kate, but not in Qt Creator and I have to use it.

Comment: Hi, did you make the kate version yourself or find it somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you could highlight CUDA code in Kate then you can do it in Qt Creator as well because in Qt Creator `generic highlighting is based on highlight definition files that are provided by the Kate Editor.`

Although Qt Creator helps you download highlight definition files (see the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.7/creator-highlighting.html#generic-highlighting)), unfortunately I can not see CUDA in the Download Definitions dialog so you have to copy the CUDA highlight definition file you use with Kate manually to the location where Qt Creator expects them (see `Location` and `Fallback location` in the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.7/creator-highlighting.html#generic-highlighting) mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

[image: A quick workaround is to add .cu and .cuh in cpp.xml in qt creator's generic-highlighter folder as below.]
A quick workaround is to add .cu and .cuh in cpp.xml in qt creator's generic-highlighter folder like above.